# If I execute this program via terminal it opens, but if I open it via .desktop file it doesn't

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, .desktop

I've installed Matlab inside /home/user/Desktop/matlabFolder/bin/ .

I can run Matlab running /home/user/Desktop/matlabFolder/bin/matlab inside a terminal, and it works.

I created a .desktop file here: /home/user/.local/share/applications/matlab.desktop and this is the content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MATLAB
Exec=/home/user/Desktop/matlabFolder/bin/matlab
Icon=/home/user/Pictures/Matlab_Logo.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;Math;Science;Education;
```

If I search for MATLAB in application launcher, I find the icon and I can start it... I can see the Matlab logo that shows that it's starting but after some seconds the logo disappears and nothing happens.....
Why? How can I try to fix? Can it be something related to ambient variables and stuff like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create keyboard shortcut for matlab with xfce](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323782/how-to-create-keyboard-shortcut-for-matlab-with-xfce) (TL;DR adapt the .desktop file provided with matlab, or use the -desktop option)

Comment: This probably applies to `.service` files, too. Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job.  Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.